# On Using the Durbin Levinson Algorithm

Tags: time-series, arima

Let  $X_t-\phi X_{t-1}=z_t+\theta Z_{t-1}$ be an ARMA(1,1) model.

GIven data $X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2$ I want to estimate $\hat{X}_3$ using the Durbin Levinson Algorithm.

The general expression is:

$\hat{X}_{n+1}=\phi_{n1}X_n+... +\phi_{nn} X_1, n\geq 1.$

My question is, given that the model is ARMA(1,1) , does the expression simplify to $\hat{X}_3=\phi_{21}X_2,$ (so that the $X_1$ data is not needed?)

What about if the process was a ARMA(2,1) model?

Comment: If I remember correctly, Durbin-Levinson is a recursive formula that is ideally used for pure AR models. Because you only have two data points, do you really need the recursive formula? It would be a lot easier just solving $\Gamma_2^{-1} \gamma_2$. And are you sure that you don't want to be using a variant of the innovations algorithm?

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. It does indeed look like I need to use the Innovations algorithm. However in the future, what would you say is the main benefit between using one algorithm over the other. Is there a difference, as they're both recursive at the end of the day.